# Why am I getting blob.Slice/blob.webkitSlice is not a function errors?

Tags: javascript, slice

Hi friendly and helpful people!

I not Web Developer at all, but unfortunately I've got to work with HTML/JavaScript/ASP.net right now. I need an Uploader which splits the to-be-uploaded files before uploading, due to file size reasons.

I've found [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1742612.aspx?How%20to%20upload%20a%20big%20file%20in%20Mvc%20) explanation online and tried to use it. Of course I edited it a little bit. My JavaScript looks like this now:

```
function upload(file) {
    var blob = file;
    var BYTES_PER_CHUNK = 1000000; // sample chunk sizes.
    var SIZE = blob.size;

    //upload content
    var start = 0;
    var end = BYTES_PER_CHUNK;
    var completed = 0;
    var count = SIZE % BYTES_PER_CHUNK == 0 ? SIZE / BYTES_PER_CHUNK : Math.floor(SIZE / BYTES_PER_CHUNK) + 1;

    while (start < SIZE) {
        var chunk = blob.Slice(start, end); // doesn't matter if use mozSlice/webkitSlice, same error

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onload = function () {
            completed = completed + 1;
            if (completed === count) {
                uploadComplete();
            }
        };
        xhr.open("POST", "/ItemTracking/MultiUpload", true);
        xhr.send(chunk);

        start = end;
        end = start + BYTES_PER_CHUNK;
    }
}
```

multiUpload() (in the following code block) will be called when a button has been clicked. It works so far. But every time I get the error that blob.Slice/blob.webkitSlice is not a function. Any ideas? What am I doing wrong? file is an HTML-Input-File (multiple) element. JavaSript is always killing me. :|

```
function multiUpload()
{
    var files = document.getElementById('file').files;
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < files.length; ++i) {
        upload(files[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You want `blob.slice` (lower case). The browser specific methods have been retracted now. Closing this as a typo

Comment: Wow. Thanks a lot. Didn't expect that, 'cause I didn't know JavaScript would be Case Sensitive in any way.